# How I can create multiple DIVs with ’append’ in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, append

I want to loop multiple DIV elements.

There are 5 books. I want to loop 5 books in ID: `BootLoop`.

What I tried?

```
my_orders.append(data[i].order.bname).appendTo("#bookLoop > div > div > div > h3");

my_orders.append(data[i].order.blink).appendTo("#bookLoop > div > div > div > a");
```

It didn't work. Where am I making a mistake?

JS:

```
var my_orders = $("#bookLoop"); 
$.each(data, function(i, order) {
     $("#bookName").append(data[i].order.bname);,
     $("#bookURL").append(data[i].order.blink);
});
```

HTML (Code structure that should be loop):

```
<div id="bookLoop">
   <div class="col-3">
      <div class="block-content">
        <div class="d-md-flex">
            <h3 id="bookName" class="h4 font-w700"></h3>
        <div>
        <div class="d-md-flex link">
           <a href="#" id="bookURL">Details</a>
        <div>
      <div>
   <div>
<div>
```

JSON:

```
[
   {"order":{"id":"61","bname":"Book 1","blink":984}},
   {"order":{"id":"42","bname":"Book 2","blink":5414}},
   {"order":{"id":"185","bname":"Book 3","blink":4521}},
   {"order":{"id":"62","bname":"Book 4","blink":41254}},
   {"order":{"id":"15","bname":"Book 5","blink":7464}}
]
```

Comment: `data[i].order.bname` can you show an example of what is this? Is this an html node?

Comment: It appears like you are doing all of this in jQuery, or? If this is really a jQuery question please update the title of the question as well as the tags

Comment: It's not clear what you want the outcome to be. Please show what is in `data` and what you want the HTML to look like.

Comment: `append` is used to add an html element. It sounds like you want to update some text. use `.text()` not `.append()`

Comment: looking to your data, is visible that `data[i].order.bname` neither `data[i].order.blink` are HTML nodes, so you probably don't want to append them. Instead use `text()` or `html()`

Comment: @CalvinNunes I added

Comment: @ControlAltDel I updated

Comment: Also, i suggest to first concat all values in a single string then use `text()`, that way you're not going to override the value each loop iteration

Comment: @HereticMonkey I added

Comment: I think that you want to create new HTML elements to each data and not append all of then inside a single `#bookName`, right?

Comment: That doesn't answer the second part, i.e., "what you want the HTML to look like" after the code has run.

Comment: @CalvinNunes No, all items will loop in the `BookLoop`. Is that something you're talking about? [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/z6VQ589F)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that what you want is to append each book and link inside `#bookLoop`, beign each book and link with it's own content.

Below I'm creating elements (nodes) to each book you have then appending it to `my_orders`.

Take a look if it is what you want, if not, please edit your question showing an example of the desired rendered HTML

```js
var my_orders = $("#bookLoop"); 
var books = ''
var links = ''

let data = [
   {"order":{"id":"61","bname":"Book 1","blink":984}},
   {"order":{"id":"42","bname":"Book 2","blink":5414}},
   {"order":{"id":"185","bname":"Book 3","blink":4521}},
   {"order":{"id":"62","bname":"Book 4","blink":41254}},
   {"order":{"id":"15","bname":"Book 5","blink":7464}}
]

$.each(data, function(i, order) {
  let col = document.createElement('div')
  col.className = 'col-3'
  
  let content = document.createElement('div')
  content.className = 'block-content'
  
  let flexC = document.createElement('div')
  flexC.className = 'd-md-flex'
  
  let title = document.createElement('h3')
  title.className = 'h4 font-w700'
  title.textContent = data[i].order.bname;
  flexC.append(title)
  
  let flexL = document.createElement('div')
  flexL.className = 'd-md-flex link'
  
  let details = document.createElement('a')
  details.className = 'bookURL'
  details.href = "#"
  details.textContent = "Details: " + data[i].order.blink
  flexL.append(details)
  
  my_orders.append(col)
  col.append(content)
  content.append(flexC)
  content.append(flexL)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bookLoop">   
<div>
```

Comment: Great work. How did you write the code so fast?  Unbelievable! But I have a little problem. I didn't write some DIV elements for the question. I didn't want the code structure to look crowded. This is the original code [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/QNHn9rri)  Can you update your code according to the original code structure? - If you do not want to do I understand - Thank you

Comment: I work everyday with dynamic data to create dynamic html... I'm not going to write the code for you, you already have this piece of code I made here to base on. But I suggest you to rethink your current structure, do you really need that deepness of nested divs? And think about what is dynamic and what is not, think where you want to append each node containing each book...